# cant detect same pixels with given color and distance

Tags: colors, cielab

Consider that two points p0 and p1 are at euclidian distance d1 and the Lab color value of given two pixels/voxels are (L0,a0,b0) and (L1,a1,b1). Now if i change the position of a rigid object which contains given two points than shouldn't it be possible to detect those points at the same distance(mm) and with the same Lab color value. 
I am using pcl to do computer vision task of 3d object recognition. Here when i try to find the two points previously detected at distance d1 and its colors and not being detected if i change the position and oriantation of the object from which given two points, voxels here were analyzed. The object is not oriented that the same two points is not visible to the kinect camera i'm using.

```
 iv=1; int p0, p1, p2, p0obj, p1obj, p2obj;
 for(p0=0;p0<a.size() && ros::ok() && iv==1;p0++) {
    for(p1=0;p1<a.size() && ros::ok() && iv==1;p1++) {
       int d1 = sqrt(pow(a.at(p1)-a.at(p0),2)+pow(b.at(p1)-b.at(p0),2)+pow(c.at(p1)-c.at(p0),2))*1000; 
       if(d1==20) { 
         for(p2=0;p2<a.size() && ros::ok() && iv==1;p2++) { 
            int d2 = sqrt(pow(a.at(p2)-a.at(p0),2)+pow(b.at(p2)-b.at(p0),2)+pow(c.at(p2)-c.at(p0),2))*1000;
            int d1d = sqrt(pow(a.at(p2)-a.at(p1),2)+pow(b.at(p2)-b.at(p1),2)+pow(c.at(p2)-c.at(p1),2))*1000;
            if(d2==20 && d1d==20) {
              float a1 = a.at(p1)-a.at(p0); float b1 = b.at(p1)-b.at(p0); float c1 = c.at(p1)-c.at(p0);
              float a2 = a.at(p2)-a.at(p0); float b2 = b.at(p2)-b.at(p0); float c2 = c.at(p2)-c.at(p0);
              float a3r = b1*c2-b2*c1; float b3r = a2*c1-a1*c2; float c3r = a1*b2-a2*b1;
              float a3, b3, c3;
              if(c3r>0) {
                a3 = a3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
                b3 = b3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
                c3 = -c3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
              }
              else {
                  a3 = a3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
                  b3 = b3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
                  c3 = c3r/sqrt(a3r*a3r+b3r*b3r+c3r*c3r);
              }
              float x3 = (a.at(p0)+a.at(p1)+a.at(p2)/3)+0.02*a3;
              float y3 = (b.at(p0)+b.at(p1)+b.at(p2)/3)+0.02*b3;
              float z3 = (c.at(p0)+c.at(p2)+c.at(p2)/3)+0.02*c3;
              for(int p4=0;p4<a.size() && ros::ok() && iv==1;p4++) {
                 int d0r = sqrt(pow(a.at(p4)-a.at(p0),2)+pow(b.at(p4)-b.at(p0),2)+pow(c.at(p4)-c.at(p0),2))*1000;
                 int d1r = sqrt(pow(a.at(p4)-a.at(p1),2)+pow(b.at(p4)-b.at(p1),2)+pow(c.at(p4)-c.at(p1),2))*1000;
                 int d2r = sqrt(pow(a.at(p4)-a.at(p2),2)+pow(b.at(p4)-b.at(p2),2)+pow(c.at(p4)-c.at(p2),2))*1000;
                 int d4r = sqrt(pow(x3-a.at(p1),2)+pow(y3-b.at(p1),2)+pow(z3-c.at(p1),2)); 
                 if(d0r>0 && d1r>0 && d2r>0 && d4r>0 && d0r<=70) {
                      cout<<p0<<endl;
                      d[0]=p0; d[1]=p1; d[2]=p2; d[3]=d0r; d[4]=d1r; d[5]=d2r; d[6]=d4r; d[7]=ac.at(p0); d[8]=bc.at(p0);
                   d[9]=ac.at(p1); d[10]=bc.at(p2); d[11]=ac.at(p2); d[12]=bc.at(p4); d[13]=ac.at(p4); d[14]=bc.at(p4); 
                   int j = arri(1,d[3],d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7],d[8],d[9],d[10],d[11],d[12],d[13],d[14]);
                   for(int k=1;k<=j;k++) { iv=0;
                      p0obj=arr0(k,d[3],d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7],d[8],d[9],d[10],d[11],d[12],d[13],d[14]);
                      p1obj=arr1(k,d[3],d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7],d[8],d[9],d[10],d[11],d[12],d[13],d[14]);
                      p2obj=arr2(k,d[3],d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7],d[8],d[9],d[10],d[11],d[12],d[13],d[14]);
                      //cout<<j<<":"<<p0obj<<"\t"<<p1obj<<"\t"<<p2obj<<"\n"<<p0<<"\t"<<p1<<"\t"<<p2<<endl;
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Above is the main part of my c++ program. Here this step analyzes present object with its coordinates in a,b,c vector and color values in ac,bc,cc vector. Here arri, arr1.. are the maps which contains the index of the point from privious object, here whenever the given point pattern p0,p1,p2,p3,p4 are detected it comes out from the loop. When i run this it is not working as expected and correctly. I have doubt that when the position and oreantation of object is changed the a,b color values of given 4 voxels also changes(from lab color) and its(given two/3/n voxels) distance also somehow do not remains same as previously saved similarly like measurement problem in physics. 
So my main confusion here is that does the values of a and b changes when the position of pixel/voxel is changed? I am not using L value since the lightness value can change in environment.

Comment: You concept seems reasonably sound, but I do not follow your code hardly at all.  You should be storing your data in some type of pcl point container (there is one for xyzrgb that would *i think* help a lot).

Comment: What exactly is in your abc vectors... It looks like you are looking at distances of every pixel in the image, which makes no sens in this context.

Comment: p3 is not present in this code snippet (despite p1,p2,p4 all being there)

Comment: I am integrating ROS and PCL to do 3d object recognition task, where first i am first reading the point cloud of type const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input to subscribe the point cloud from camera and than converting it to PCL data type pcl::PointXYZRGB by using pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> output;
pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,output);

Comment: ok, but if you have pcl points, why generate these confusing vectors of attributes rather than just using PCL built in point functions like pt.distance(pt)...

Comment: Here (a,b,c) is coordinates of object saved which is used in this node to detect the matched points latter and (lc,ac,bc) are Lab color for each of those points. Here p3 is (x3,y3,z3) and do not belong to object, i call it virtual point, it is used for matching the point pattern one by one. Here the points are voxels containing color information, and p0obj, p2obj, p3obj, are the index of points from previous object saved which has been detected in present analysed object. Her by doing this not just the index of point but also the oriantation of present object w.r.t previously saved same..

Comment: Here i am using seperate distance formula instead of  template<typename PointT >float pcl::geometry::distance(const PointT &   p1,const PointT &  p2) which can be used to find distance between two points in a point cloud because here the vectors (a,b,c) do not represent points from pointcloud itself and its size is also different, these are the points which is detected, by analysing the moved points. I am first detecting the moved points in image right now so that the main base concept of this theory can be first berified.

Comment: My issue is with your container choice, regardless of where they are from or what they represent, your vectors abc are just pts that your are calculating distance between with a regular distance equation.  Using (even your own) an actual container object will make this code 100% more readable...

Comment: I could be wrong (still pretty noob here), but I am fairly confident that your question as currently stated will get little to no response here due to its format (both the code and how confusing your explanation is).  Pictures, data, specific failures, and clear flow will all greatly improve this question and the response to it.

Comment: Ok, i got what u said, and i will do that from now before discussing with othes so that they will understand it easily.

Comment: well since i haven't that much reputation in this forum, i am not being able to post test snapshots from my window, i can even edit my comment he he.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 suggestions:

use approximate distances (a>19 && a<21), (a==20) is incredibly specific and could fail due to digital voxeling noise depending on your resolution and object size.

I would think that you need to check to see if your color matches/ is the correct color to be qualified points, but I see this no where in your code.

If I were writing this... I think my first step would be separating out all pixels inside a certain color range and then I would look through those points for a set of properly spaced items among them.

Comment: I have done that also, but the result: the oriantation and position of the object is not coming properly, although little much difference in both position and oriantation is ok, but the oriantaion is coming totally wrong when i put the test object in some specific oriantation. although i will work on that also cas that is also true, their must be some mistake in my code.

Comment: I can post all my codes until i finish this myself, so i havent posted all codes.

Comment: Yes, the steps to this problem imo::(1):demonstrate that you can clearly segment out the colors that you want. (2): Make a function to get the center of colored clusters so that you now have pts which represent your fiducials. (3):Implement the appropriate vector math to calculate transformation of those 3 points from origin position...